# CodeIgniter and Authorize.net CIM library

Tags: xml, codeigniter, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I'm trying to use the authorize.net library for CI2.0 from https://github.com/cloudmanic/codeignitor-authorizenet-cim-library

When running fulltest() which is the first function in the controller I get:

Creating Customer Profile - create_customer_profile()

> Error: The element
>   'createCustomerProfileRequest' in
>   namespace
>   'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'
>   has invalid child element
>   'createCustomerProfileRequest' in
>   namespace
>   'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.
>   List of possible elements expected:
>   'validationMode' in namespace
>   'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means one of the XML nodes is in the wrong place. Authorize.Net's API is very picky about the format of any XML sent to it. It's hard to say for sure exactly what the error is without seeing the XML generated but it probably has to do with the `validationMode` element being placed incorrectly.

You can see what a valid XML format looks like in the [CIM Guide](http://www.authorize.net/support/CIM_XML_guide.pdf) on page 26.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your response. I've been pulling my hair since yesterday over this. I'm using https://github.com/cloudmanic/codeignitor-authorizenet-cim-library to tie in to CodeIgniter. 

I'm going to give it another shot, if it doesnt work out I will probably head over to your tutorial on http://www.johnconde.net/blog/tutorial-integrate-the-authorize-net-cim-api-with-php/

Comment: John that did it - I made a few adjustments to that library and got it working. I will be posting the changes to the net soon.Thank again for your pointer

Comment: John, I keep getting transaction declined using CIM with auth only (not capture) however I do see the transactions in my CIM overview in my live account? Any ideas?

Comment: @Sean did you get it figured out?

Comment: @JasonShultz If you are having an issue similar to this one feel free to [ask your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) so we can attempt to help you with it.